# How to run only a few benchmark tests with a jar file in JMH?

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

I have the following JMH with 3 benchmark tests:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(1)

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class TestBenchmark {
    private CW cw;

    @Param({"C:data.csv"})
    public String fileName;


    @Param({"100"})
    public int id;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        cw = new CW(fileName);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void method1() {
        cw.method1(id);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void method2() {
        cw.method2(id);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void method3() {
        cw.method3(id);
    }

}
```

I ran `mvn clean install` to compile a benchmark.jar. Now I'd like to only run benchmark tests for method1 and method2, not method3, how can I do it?

I tried `java -jar benchmark.jar -f "method1|method2", but got error:

```
Error parsing command line:
 Cannot parse argument 'method1|method2' of option f
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `-f` property is a number of forks, not files, so it must be `int` value.
Second, in your  particular case you could exclude `method3()` with `-e` flag:

```bash
$ java -jar target/benchmarks.jar -e package-name.TestBenchmark.method3
```

Pay attention, that value of `-e` is regexp.
For debugging purposes you could use `-l` flag listing the benchmarks that match a filter, and exit.